# Correct Ffmpeg record settings for playing files back in Windows built in players?

Tags: windows-10, video, ffmpeg

I'm using Ffmpeg to record screen videos in Windows 10:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f gdigrab -framerate 29.97 -draw_mouse 0 -offset_x 2777 -offset_y 344 -video_size 1280x720 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -preset ultrafast D:/myvideo.mpg
```

If I play the recorded files in VLC they work fine.  If I play them back in a built in Windows Media Player or "Movies & TV"  I get this error code: 0xc10100be ERROR_INVALID_MODULETYPE

Are there any settings I need to add to Ffmpeg for use in Windows?

Comment: Use `.mp4` instead of `.mpg`.

Comment: Sorry I just made an edit.  Also changing the file name to mp4, mpg or mpeg doesn't make any difference, get the same error.

Comment: Did you simply change the name of the existing file, or did you actually re-run the command with the proper output name (`myvideo.mp4`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big thanks to @LordNeckbeard.  I was forgetting that "mpg" files are not containers like "mp4".  Good roundup [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats).

So part 1 was setting the output file type to ".mp4".  This at least stopped the crashes and errors but was still getting black video in Windows players.  Part 2 was setting the pixel format to yuv420p.  From [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264):

> **Encoding for dumb players**
>
> You may need to use `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`)
> for your output to work in QuickTime and most other players. These
> players only supports the YUV planar color space with 4:2:0 chroma
> subsampling for H.264 video.

Here's the ffmpeg command that works, I'm sure it needs more optimization:

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f gdigrab -framerate 29.97 -draw_mouse 0 -offset_x 2633 -offset_y 103 -video_size 1280x720 -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264  -preset ultrafast D:/myvideo.mp4
```